# Pine 5 - History lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like to insert an input relating to the history of the lines to be shown in the chart. I've already tried different ways but I've not obtained desired results, do you have any ideas how I can do it?

I've tried to settle this variable as input:

```
var int HistoryLength = input.int(20, title="Historical Bars", minval=1)
```

but honestly I'm trying to figure out where i can allocate it. I'm not sure if it should be in the

```
line.new(x1=lastDojiIndex, y1=lastDojiBodyMid, x2=lastDojiIndex + LineLong, y2=lastDojiBodyMid, width=lineWidth, color=lineColor)
```

This is the whole code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("D Lines", shorttitle="D Lines", overlay=true)



var int LineLongInput = input.int(25, title="Line Length")
var color LineColorInput = input.color(color.rgb(19, 132, 117), title="Line Color")
var int LineWidthInput = input.int(1, title="Line Width")

drawHorizontalLineFromDoji(LineLong, lineColor, lineWidth) =>
    // Calcola la dimensione del corpo del doji
    dojiSize = math.abs(open - close)

    isDoji = dojiSize < (high - low) * 0.1

    var int lastDojiIndex = na
    var float lastDojiBodyMid = na
    if isDoji
        lastDojiIndex := bar_index
        lastDojiBodyMid := (open + close) / 2

        line.new(x1=lastDojiIndex, y1=lastDojiBodyMid, x2=lastDojiIndex + LineLong, y2=lastDojiBodyMid, width=lineWidth, color=lineColor)

var int HistoryLength = input.int(20, title="Historical Bars", minval=1)  // Aggiunto l'input per il numero di barre storiche

drawHorizontalLineFromDoji(HistoryLength, LineColorInput, LineWidthInput)
```

I would like to have the history of the lines that I can modify at will in the list of options

Answer (score 0):

You need an array to do that.

You need to add each line to this array but before you do that, check the length of the array. If there are too many lines in the array, get the first line from the array and delete it.

```
f_add_to_array(p_array, p_max_cnt, p_new_line) =>
    len = array.size(p_array)

    if (len >= p_max_cnt)
        first_line = array.shift(p_array)  // Removes an array's first element and returns its value.
        line.delete(first_line)

    array.push(p_array, p_new_line)
```